# Why would touches not be registering on the bottom of the screen in React-Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm attempting to put a floating button over a ListView in my React-Native application on iOS. The appearance is great, but the functionality of my TouchableHighlight is not so great...

```
<TouchableHighlight
   onPress={() => {
   this.myAction()
   }}>
   <View style={styles.floatingCameraButton}>
       <Image source={camera_icon} style={styles.cameraIcon}/>
   </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

That's my code for the button, and here are my stylings:

```
floatingCameraButton: {
   height: 80,
   width: 80,
   borderRadius: 40,
   backgroundColor: '#aa2222',
   position: 'absolute',
   bottom: 20,
   right: 20,
   shadowColor: '#000000',
   shadowOpacity: 0.8,
   shadowRadius: 2,
   shadowOffset: {
     height: 5,
     width: 5
   },
},
```

For some reason, when the button is touched on the lower portion of the screen, the touch fails to register on the button.

I've tested making the button taller and also moving in up, and both of those are solutions, but not ones I am interested in.

My assumption is that somehow React-Native is masking my touches that occur where the iOS native Tab Bar would be (meaning the bottom 50px). However, I do not have a Tab Bar on the screen, nor have I implemented one. I do have a Navigator that is wrapping the view which my button is in, not sure if that could be the culprit.

Any ideas or help to get my TouchableHighlight to be touchable on the bottom 50px of the screen would be very helpful.

Comment: `I do have a that is wrapping the view which my button is in` Sorry?

Comment: Have a Navigator sorry it was wrapped in less-than and greater-than and disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Try applying your styles to the TouchableHighlight itself.

```
<TouchableHighlight
   style={styles.floatingCameraButton}
   onPress={() => this.myAction()}>
       <Image source={camera_icon} style={styles.cameraIcon}/>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Tried this and still only partially clicking works. Not sure how else to switch things up at this point